# UDev Rule Raspberry PI Won't Start Web app

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, udev

So first things first.  I am attempting to write a custom udev rule for a raspberry pi running the latest jessie raspbian.  The rule I am attempting to write consists of a script to run a script to launch Flask web app. But the problem is that the webapp never starts.  I can run usbinsert from terminal and it works just fine.  I can run runWebApp.sh from terminal and it works.  I would take any guidance or suggestions at this point.

I have tried using different usb devices and changing the rule to suit the needs.  I have tried using just an action, kernel, and run in the udev rule.  I know this much.  The udev rule runs and I can see the script it is supposed to be running run.

This is the rule (/etc/udev/rules.d/99-z.rules):

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sda*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05e3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0743", RUN+="/lib/udev/usbinsert"
```

This is the monitor capture by running udevadm monitor --environment:

```
KERNEL[7892.634962] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/024
DEVNUM=024
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4
DEVTYPE=usb_device
MAJOR=189
MINOR=23
PRODUCT=5e3/743/819
SEQNUM=1492
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

KERNEL[7892.650572] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=8/6/80
MODALIAS=usb:v05E3p0743d0819dc00dsc00dp00ic08isc06ip50in00
PRODUCT=5e3/743/819
SEQNUM=1493
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

KERNEL[7892.659504] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17
DEVTYPE=scsi_host
SEQNUM=1494
SUBSYSTEM=scsi

KERNEL[7892.659883] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/scsi_host/host17 (scsi_host)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/scsi_host/host17
SEQNUM=1495
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_host

UDEV  [7892.692301] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/024
DEVNUM=024
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=USB_Storage
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Storage
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=SDXC and microSDXC CardReader
ID_MODEL_ID=0743
ID_REVISION=0819
ID_SERIAL=Generic_USB_Storage_000000000819
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=000000000819
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_VENDOR=Generic
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Generic
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Genesys Logic, Inc.
ID_VENDOR_ID=05e3
MAJOR=189
MINOR=23
PRODUCT=5e3/743/819
SEQNUM=1492
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=92636029

UDEV  [7892.705663] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=SDXC and microSDXC CardReader
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Genesys Logic, Inc.
INTERFACE=8/6/80
MODALIAS=usb:v05E3p0743d0819dc00dsc00dp00ic08isc06ip50in00
PRODUCT=5e3/743/819
SEQNUM=1493
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=653207

UDEV  [7892.715238] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17
DEVTYPE=scsi_host
SEQNUM=1494
SUBSYSTEM=scsi
USEC_INITIALIZED=669795

UDEV  [7892.725906] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/scsi_host/host17 (scsi_host)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/scsi_host/host17
SEQNUM=1495
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_host
USEC_INITIALIZED=670426

KERNEL[7893.652232] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0
DEVTYPE=scsi_target
SEQNUM=1496
SUBSYSTEM=scsi

KERNEL[7893.652473] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0
DEVTYPE=scsi_device
MODALIAS=scsi:t-0x00
SEQNUM=1497
SUBSYSTEM=scsi

KERNEL[7893.652666] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_disk/17:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_disk/17:0:0:0
SEQNUM=1498
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_disk

KERNEL[7893.652840] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_device/17:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_device/17:0:0:0
SEQNUM=1499
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_device

UDEV  [7893.657235] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0
DEVTYPE=scsi_target
SEQNUM=1496
SUBSYSTEM=scsi
USEC_INITIALIZED=653154

KERNEL[7893.658401] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/sg0
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0
MAJOR=21
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1500
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_generic

KERNEL[7893.664483] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/bsg/17:0:0:0 (bsg)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/bsg/17:0:0:0
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/bsg/17:0:0:0
MAJOR=252
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1501
SUBSYSTEM=bsg

UDEV  [7893.673356] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0 (scsi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0
DEVTYPE=scsi_device
MODALIAS=scsi:t-0x00
SEQNUM=1497
SUBSYSTEM=scsi
USEC_INITIALIZED=653491

UDEV  [7893.685914] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_disk/17:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_disk/17:0:0:0
SEQNUM=1498
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_disk
USEC_INITIALIZED=653657

UDEV  [7893.696161] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_device/17:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_device/17:0:0:0
SEQNUM=1499
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_device
USEC_INITIALIZED=93653853

UDEV  [7893.705375] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/sg0
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0
MAJOR=21
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1500
SUBSYSTEM=scsi_generic
USEC_INITIALIZED=93667362

UDEV  [7893.708119] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/bsg/17:0:0:0 (bsg)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/bsg/17:0:0:0
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/bsg/17:0:0:0
MAJOR=252
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1501
SUBSYSTEM=bsg
USEC_INITIALIZED=93667594

KERNEL[7894.054150] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/bdi/8:0
SEQNUM=1502
SUBSYSTEM=bdi

UDEV  [7894.056350] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/bdi/8:0
SEQNUM=1502
SUBSYSTEM=bdi
USEC_INITIALIZED=54531

KERNEL[7894.067936] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/sda
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/block/sda
DEVTYPE=disk
MAJOR=8
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1503
SUBSYSTEM=block

KERNEL[7894.069129] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/sda1
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
DEVTYPE=partition
MAJOR=8
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=1504
SUBSYSTEM=block

UDEV  [7894.322991] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic_STORAGE_DEVICE_000000000819-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
DEVNAME=/dev/sda
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/block/sda
DEVTYPE=disk
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INSTANCE=0:0
ID_MODEL=STORAGE_DEVICE
ID_MODEL_ENC=STORAGE\x20DEVICE\x20\x20
ID_MODEL_ID=0743
ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
ID_PATH=platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
ID_PATH_TAG=platform-20980000_usb-usb-0_1_4_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
ID_REVISION=0819
ID_SERIAL=Generic_STORAGE_DEVICE_000000000819-0:0
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=000000000819
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=Generic
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Generic\x20
ID_VENDOR_ID=05e3
MAJOR=8
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=1503
SUBSYSTEM=block
TAGS=:systemd:
UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE=1
UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_COUNT=1
UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_SCHEME=mbr
UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY=0
USEC_INITIALIZED=73494

UDEV  [7894.728158] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic_STORAGE_DEVICE_000000000819-0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-path/platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-uuid/166E-33D9
DEVNAME=/dev/sda1
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
DEVTYPE=partition
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FS_TYPE=vfat
ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
ID_FS_UUID=166E-33D9
ID_FS_UUID_ENC=166E-33D9
ID_FS_VERSION=FAT32
ID_INSTANCE=0:0
ID_MODEL=STORAGE_DEVICE
ID_MODEL_ENC=STORAGE\x20DEVICE\x20\x20
ID_MODEL_ID=0743
ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=8:0
ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=1
ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=8192
ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME=dos
ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE=60866560
ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE=0xc
ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
ID_PATH=platform-20980000.usb-usb-0:1.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
ID_PATH_TAG=platform-20980000_usb-usb-0_1_4_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
ID_REVISION=0819
ID_SERIAL=Generic_STORAGE_DEVICE_000000000819-0:0
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=000000000819
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=Generic
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Generic\x20
ID_VENDOR_ID=05e3
MAJOR=8
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=1504
SUBSYSTEM=block
TAGS=:systemd:
UDISKS_PARTITION=1
UDISKS_PARTITION_ALIGNMENT_OFFSET=0
UDISKS_PARTITION_NUMBER=1
UDISKS_PARTITION_OFFSET=4194304
UDISKS_PARTITION_SCHEME=mbr
UDISKS_PARTITION_SIZE=31163678720
UDISKS_PARTITION_SLAVE=/sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/block/sda
UDISKS_PARTITION_TYPE=0x0c
UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY=0
USEC_INITIALIZED=73822
```

I know the script is running because I see it in the output of top:

```
usbinsert        945 root      0.0  0.6    0    0   74
usb-storage      918 root      0.0  0.0    0    0    0
udisksd          835 root      0.0  1.5    0    2  729
```

The permissions for the udev rule, usbinsert script and runWebapp.sh are as follows respectively:

```
pi@IT:~ $ ls -la /etc/udev/rules.d/99-z.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 130 Feb  1 07:27 /etc/udev/rules.d/99-z.rules

pi@IT:~ $ ls -la /lib/udev/usbinsert
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 58 Feb  1 06:20 /lib/udev/usbinsert

pi@IT:~ $ lla /home/pi/Documents/scripts/runWebApp.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Feb  1 07:08 /home/pi/Documents/scripts/runWebApp.sh
```

The contents of usbinsert:

```
#!/bin/sh

/home/pi/Documents/scripts/runWebApp.sh & exit
```

The contents of runWebApp.sh (I have tried this four ways):

1.

```
    #!/bin/sh

    lxterminal -e python /home/pi/webapp/app.py
```

2.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    lxterminal -e python /home/pi/webapp/app.py
```

3.

```
    #!/bin/sh

    python /home/pi/webapp/app.py
```

4.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    python /home/pi/webapp/app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem accessing display. try to set the display in the script

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```